# Branch.io: Deeplinking goes to custom URL on return

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, branch.io

In Branch.io, I created a branch and posted the link to Facebook successfully. Here is my configuration on branch.io dashboard:

[image: config]

This is the link on facebook:

[image: facebook link]

I click on it, it redirects me to my app successfully. Within a few seconds of the bottom screen appear, my app starts:

[image: redirect]

Now, I return to facebook by closing my app and starting facebook - the facebook built in browser seems to be continuing with going to the custom URL of (www.yahoo.com):

[image: yahoo]

Within a few seconds, yahoo opens:

[image: yahoo]

I would have thought that once the redirect was successful, the Facebook built-in browser would have closed and when you return to facebook, facebook would appear. I would not have expected the built-in browser to continue with the custom url as though your app was not installed.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you check in the settings for Facebook you will see by default, Links Open externally is set to off.

[image]

This is definitely a nuisance when it comes to deep links especially from Facebook.

I have never used branch.io but i am assuming it is able to intercept this behavior of the deeplink open the link externally, but this does not stop Facebook from trying to render in the browser without this turned off. And it is probably unrealistic to think your users will all have this turned off by default.

But for testing now, i would turn Links Open externally to on, and see if for the time being it helps stop the issue.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it makes sense - the link opens in the browser instead and then the browser opens my app. If I close my app and navigate back to the browser, the browser now keeps on going to my custom url. I feel rather we have move the problem to the browser from facebook.

Comment: @Simon yeah, i believe its not a problem with bridge.io, because if you try the same thing with twitter I am sure you will observe this behavior because they now open all links internally to the app, as well as linkedin